# Editable Table using DataTables that uses a dynamic data source (JSON) which then updates the data source when edits are made

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables

I am using the Datatables plugin and i am populating it using html which is rendered from a JSON array, however, i need it to render the table from this JSON array and for it to be dynamic so that if an edit is made it then updates the model (datasource) which is stored client side.

Each time you go to a new page on the table it renders the html using the data stored in the model (datasource).

I was wondering if this is at all possible using datatables and if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be fantastic! If you need any more information please let me know!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this with datatables using the DataTables Editor https://editor.datatables.net/